# Как сделать фиксированными хедер и меню при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Задача состоит в том что (пример):

Есть хедер там лого социалки номер и пару кнопок, под ним меню.
И вот при скролле вниз страницы, было бы не плохо например, скрывать и удалять социалки и номер. А рядом с лого что бы всплывало меню, и всё это фиксировалось.

если не понятно обьяснил, вот пример - http://istv.uz/

В каком направление мне искать информацию что бы реализовать что похожее ?

Answer (score 1):

> Вообще, следовало бы потрудиться над грамотным описанием проблемы. А
>   то просто моветон. Ошибок наделали, да и **по смыслу не совсем ясно есть ли проблема вообще?**

[Первый вариант](http://pcvector.net/scripts/other/477-headroom-lipkiy-header.html)

[Второй](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=1882)

[**Самый лучший с которого следовало начинать**](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&ei=5HxVW4OYJszb6QT4npi4DA&q=%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B&oq=%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.33i22i29i30k1.268348.281778.0.283588.45.31.7.7.9.0.572.4606.0j3j10j3j0j1.17.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..15.30.4534...0j0i131k1j0i67k1j0i131i67k1j0i22i30k1.0.axyJfPwBZSw)